# Error after open iTerm-zsh or Terminal

Tags: macos, installation, zsh

I am not sure what I've set on my iTerm-zsh last night.

But after I open iTerm (zsh) or Terminal on my Mac or I try to use zsh, 
it will always show the following:

```
/Users/Simon/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc:3: = not found`    
/Users/Simon/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc:18: command not found: complete
/Users/Simon/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc:29: parse error near `]]'
```

Any ideas that I can fix this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: shouldn't need the quotes around your path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset my zsh configuration, remove all instances of .zshrc and any .zshrc.??? swap files solve the problem :)

Command to reset -> `rm -f ~/.zshrc*`

Then close my terminal session and re-open, and I get the "new user" screen.

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue but accepted answer will remove any configuration on zsh. But You can fix by modifying `bash_profile`

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

change following

```
if [ -f '[PATH_TO_FOLDER]/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' ]; then . '[PATH_TO_FOLDER]/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '[PATH_TO_FOLDER]/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc' ]; then . '[PATH_TO_FOLDER]/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'; fi
```

to

```
if [ -f '[PATH_TO_FOLDER]/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc' ]; then . '[PATH_TO_FOLDER]/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '[PATH_TO_FOLDER]/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc' ]; then . '[PATH_TO_FOLDER]/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc'; fi
```

lastly run

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Big Sur try to execute these commands:

```
. '/your_installation_path/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc'
. '/your_installation_path/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc'
```