# gcloud command not found - while installing Google Cloud SDK

Tags: terminal, installation, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am on a mac and am trying to install the Google Cloud SDK (including the gcloud command line utility) using this command in terminal

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

as seen at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

It got all the way to the end and finished but even after I restarted my shell, the `gcloud` command still says it's not found.

Why isn't this installation working?

Comment: Which shell are you using? The installer prompts about updating your `.bashrc` file, but does not (yet) work with zsh or other shells. zsh support in the installer is on the way. Did you answer `y` when the installer prompted `Modify profile to update your $PATH and enable bash completion? (Y/n)?`?

Comment: Actually yes, I saw that, but it didn't actually prompt me. It didn't wait for my response, so I didn't get to say YES. Therefore, the installer didn't do that step.    I'm wondering how to make a more permanent fix now, because it seems like my fix only worked for the one time and I had to do it again today to fix it again. Suggestions?

Comment: Actually I just re-installed it this time and the prompt worked, so now I'm all good. Thanks

Comment: When I installed gcloud the install modified the profile (e.g. `~/.bash_profile`) but it failed to reload it. Running `source ~/.bash_profile` fixed it.

Comment: following nicks notes, i ran `source ~/.bashrc` instead and it seemed to fix it for me since i didnt have a bash_profile.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

So below is my previous fix for this problem, but it turns out it isn't permanent. It works but every time you restart Terminal, you'd have to do the same thing which isn't practical.

So that is why I suggest you delete the current google-cloud-sdk directory, and just redo the installation. Be sure (as Zachary has mentioned) to answer yes (Y) to the prompt `Modify profile to update your $PATH and enable bash completion? (Y/n)`.

Here is my old answer, but just redo the installation:

> I had the same problem, `gcloud` wasn't working for me. But then, in the same directory as my `google-cloud-sdk` folder which I had just installed (my `home` directory), I found this file called `test`. Inside this `test` file I found two commands:

```sh
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
source '[path-to-my-home]/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'
# The next line enables bash completion for gcloud.
source '[path-to-my-home]/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
```

> After I ran these two `source` commands in terminal, `gcloud` worked!

Comment: For zsh, there are corresponding `path.zsh.inc` and `completion.zsh.inc` files.

Comment: Well guys in my case i just forgot to close and open the terminal window after instalation.... hope this help any body :D

Comment: Unfortunately, this is no longer a question in the latest install.sh

Comment: Current gcloud install package has somehow forked up this step.

Comment: gcloud has shell script to help with this now after you download the gcloud `tar.gz` from their site, then run `./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh`.  which will basically do the above commands for you when you follow the steps

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos

Comment: The QuickStart for macOS doesn't add the source command just adds it to the path. Which is a problem. This solution helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Won't work for me because despite installing it the same way it disappears after install, completely vanishing, there is no google-cloud-sdk dir.

Comment: those source files are copied into the bashrc file by the end of the installation. 
so `source ~/.bashrc`(rc file, wherever it is on the disk) should help you get going

Answer (score 83):

***How to install GCloud and Always Works after Restart On Mac OS HIGH Sierra:***

1. Download install package 
   [Here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos)
2. Achieved file and drop in your folder
3. Open terminal, go to your folder with file and enter this command:

   ```
    ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
   ```
4. "Modify profile to update your `$PATH` and enable bash completion?" 
     **Yes**
5. Enter this path to modify:
   `/Users/USERNAME_COMPUTER/.bashrc`
6. After  all install, enter this:

   ```
     source ~/.bashrc
   ```
7. Enter this to check install gcloud:

   gcloud  - -version
8. Open new window terminal `cmd+n`
   ***DONT CLOSE OLD WINDOW*** and enter in new window `gcloud version`

   if: **«command not found» go to step 9**

   else: Congratulations GCloud work in terminal
9. Return to old window and enter `echo $PATH`
   and copy path to GCloud
10. Open BASH_PROFILE:

    ```
    open ~/.bash_profile
    ```
11. Enter path to new Bash:

    ```
    « export PATH="/Users/USERNAME_COMPUTER/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH" »
    ```
12. Return to step 8

Comment: Thank you so much this did help :)

Answer (score 80):

Same here, I try

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then, It worked

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: source ~/.zshrc for macOS CATALINA

Answer (score 47):

This one worked for me:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Worked for me as well

Comment: first `export PATH="/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH"` then this command above.

Answer (score 33):

On Mac/Linux, you'll need to enter the following entry in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: It worked on mac as well. The PATH variable will need to be set.

Comment: @ParthBhoiwala Thanks for letting me know, I've updated the answer. :)

Comment: Only answer working with the new version, where the 'add variables to path' prompt is absent.

Comment: This one worked for me. My installation didn't update .bashrc on its own.

Comment: In my case, it was `export PATH="$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH"` as I had installed the SDK folder in my home directory.

Answer (score 27):

I'm running zsh and found this gist very helpful: https://gist.github.com/dwchiang/10849350

Edit the **~/.zshrc** file to include these two lines:

```
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
source /Users/YOUR_USERNAME/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc

# The next line enables zsh completion for gcloud.
source /Users/YOUR_USERNAME/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc
```

This assumes you installed the package in your main directory from the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 24):

I had this issue today, and adding `sudo` to the `install command` fixed my issue on maxOS Sierra!

```
sudo ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
```

Comment: This is the only thing that helped me on Sierra - none of the other answers worked.

Comment: This also fixed my problem on macOS v10.13 "High Sierra"

Comment: you need to put the .zshrc when the installation program ask for the file bash that are using you. so you need to put some like this:    /Users/YOU-NAME-USER/.zshrc

Answer (score 24):

In my case, I switched the terminal from bash to zsh after I installed Google Cloud SDK, so it showed the 'zsh: command not found: gcloud' error.

It's solved by running

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Note that all this does is to execute the .zshrc file which should have been executed when the terminal opened. So, the question is, why was it not executed? In my case, the reason was that as I downloaded the SDK it was placed on my Downloads directory where it was deleted at some point in time. Place the SDK in a folder where it's not going to be deleted, run the install.sh script again, and it will load it on startup every time.

Answer (score 22):

When installing the SDK I used this method:

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

When using this method from the original author make sure you have accepted the security preferences in your mac settings to allow apps downloaded from app store and identified developers.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I had to add the sudo in front

Answer (score 16):

You just have to execute this command as root

```
$ curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

Restart the terminal and that's it. Now all commands should be executed as root

Answer (score 16):

I know this question has been answered, but here are my two cent. 
After installing gcloud, you need to restart the shell before you able to gcloud command.

How you do this, mostly depends on the file you keep your shell configuration. Most files are `.bashrc_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`.

You can now restart with

`source ~/.bashrc_profile`

You can replace the file to the file you have.

Or if you don't care the file you have, on Mac or linux you can restart the shell .

`exec -l $SHELL`

Answer (score 16):

You have to add the command to the path

Run

> `brew info --cask google-cloud-sdk`

and find the lines to append to  `~/.zshrc`

The lines to append can be obtained from the output of the previous command. For zsh users, It should be some like these:

```sh
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/libexec/bin/python"
source "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc"
source "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc"
```

(or choose the proper ones from the command output depending un the Shell you are using)

Comment: This nuance is specified on the [gcloud brew page](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/google-cloud-sdk). Although I'm not sure if the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON variable needs to be exported

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

I had to source my bash_profile file.  To do so,

1. Open up a Terminal session.
2. In that session type:
   source .bash_profile and then press enter

Now, the gcloud command should work

Answer (score 7):

To launch it on MacOs Sierra, after install gcloud I modified my .bash_profile

Original lines:

```
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/Users/alejandro/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' ]; then . '/Users/alejandro/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '/Users/alejandro/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc' ]; then . '/Users/alejandro/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'; fi
```

updated to:

```
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/Users/alejandro/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' ]; then source '/Users/alejandro/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '/Users/alejandro/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc' ]; then source '/Users/alejandro/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'; fi
```

Restart the terminal and all become to work as expected!

Answer (score 7):

for oh-my-zsh run on terminal after install

```bash
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me :

After saying `Y` to `Modify profile to update your $PATH and enable bash completion? (Y/n)?`

Google initiation is prompting this : `Enter a path to an rc file to update, or leave blank to use` and the default path was : `[/Users/MY_USERSAME/.bash_profile]:` but instead of pressing `enter`, I wrote : `/Users/MY_USERNAME/.bashrc` to change the path.

This would overwrite the default location that Google suggest.

Then, I only had to do `source ~/.bashrc` and everything works now!

Comment: This fixed my problem. I was typing ~/.bash_profile and the installation wasn't not updating the path, but also not outputting an error.

Answer (score 5):

If you're a macOS homebrew zsh user:

1. `brew cask install google-cloud-sdk`
2. Update your ~/.zshrc:

```
plugins=(
  ...
  gcloud
)
```

3. Open new shell.

Answer (score 4):

Using `.zsh shell` you can just try to add `glcoud` in [plugin list](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Plugins) in the `~/.zshrc` file.

```
plugins=(
  gcloud
)
```

If that doesn't work, try this: (updated [Krishna's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2545550/krishna) answer)

1. Update the `~/.zshrc` file

```
# Updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
source /Users/austris/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc

# Enables zsh completion for gcloud.
source /Users/austris/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc
```

2. Update the `google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc` file with following

```
script_link="$( readlink "$0" )" || script_link="$0" 
apparent_sdk_dir="${script_link%/*}" 
if [[ "$apparent_sdk_dir" == "$script_link" ]]; then
  apparent_sdk_dir=. 
fi
sdk_dir="$( cd -P "$apparent_sdk_dir" && pwd -P )" 
bin_path="$sdk_dir/bin" 
export PATH=$bin_path:$PATH
```

**double square brackets at the third line were missing from the original answer*

Answer (score 4):

After inspecting the installation zip by running `./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --help`, the parameter `--path-update` worked for me. Use it as follows,

```
./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --path-update true
```

It will automatically add the PATH update to the .bash*rc* (see `--rc-path` parameter for different rc files). Add the `--quiet` parameter for no interactivity.

Answer (score 4):

Tested on Mac

#### 1. Installation

If did this already -> skip this step

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

#### 2. Enable `gcloud` command line

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

If not works, try below

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

If not works, try below

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank-you for not assuming anything and listing all the possible alternates.

Answer (score 3):

I found incorrect `if-fi` statements in my `~/.bash_profile`
*(no if condition in the next block)*

`source '/Users/yorko/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'`

`fi`

I just had to remove `"fi"` and run `"source ~/.bash_profile"` to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on MAC OS and using ***.zsh*** shell then do the following:

1. Edit your `.zshrc` and add the following

   ```
   # The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
   source /Users/USER_NAME/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc

   # The next line enables zsh completion for gcloud.
   source /Users/USER_NAME/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc
   ```
2. Create new file named `path.zsh.inc` under your home directory(/Users/USER_NAME/):

   ```
   script_link="$( readlink "$0" )" || script_link="$0"
   apparent_sdk_dir="${script_link%/*}"
   if [ "$apparent_sdk_dir" == "$script_link" ]; then
    apparent_sdk_dir=.
   fi
   sdk_dir="$( cd -P "$apparent_sdk_dir" && pwd -P )"
   bin_path="$sdk_dir/bin"
   export PATH=$bin_path:$PATH
   ```

Checkout more @ [Official Docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos)

Answer (score 2):

If running

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

results in "No such file or directory"

On windows:

1. Go to c/Users/
2. While holding shift, right-click .bashrc file and select "Copy as path"
3. In bash:  `source <pasteCopiedPathHere>` -> for example: `source "C:\Users\John\.bashhrc"`

Answer (score 2):

If you are running ZSH shell in MacOS you should rerun the installation and when you be asked for this question:

```
Modify profile to update your $PATH and enable shell command 
completion?
```

answer `YES`

and

```
Enter a path to an rc file to update, or leave blank to use 
    [/Users/your_user/.bash_profile]:
```

answer(your zshrc path): `/Users/your_user/.zshrc`

Restart Terminal and that's all.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answers, depending on your distro, it may be necessary to execute the bash command from the command line before calling your gsutil command. This is the case for distros that have tcsh or other shell as the default. By typing "bash" the source is changed to the .bashrc file and the file is executed.

```
# Step 1
bash
# Step 2
gsutil 
#Step 3: profit!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
```

and then

```
Enter a path to an rc file to update, or leave blank to use 
[/Users/uer/.bash_profile]:  "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH"
```

result:

```
["/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH"] has been updated.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using zsh with Mac, after installation and [initialization](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install), you just need `source ~./zshrc` to apply the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Post installation instructions are not clear:

```
==> Source [/.../google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc] in your profile to enable shell command completion for gcloud.
==> Source [/.../google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc] in your profile to add the Google Cloud SDK command line tools to your $PATH.
```

I had to actually add the following lines of code in my `.bash_profile` for `gcloud` to work:

```
source '/.../google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
source '/.../google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
```

I ran this in the root directory and it worked. I'm running macOS Mojave Version 10.14.3.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this command on Ubuntu/Linux:

```
sudo ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
```

Close the terminal or open a new window as the log says:

> ==> Start a new shell for the changes to take effect.

Once it is done try installing any package by glcloud command:

```
gcloud components install app-engine-php
```

It won't show the error.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of my installation failure:

- I am running a zsh terminal and the `install.sh` inserts `path.bash.inc` into my `.bash_profile`

fix:

1. `cd [whereever]/google-cloud-sdk && ./install.sh`
2. `vi ~/.bash_profile`
3. replace all instances of `path.bash.inc` with `path.zsh.inc`

os config:

- macOS Catalina
- zsh

ref:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61491744/1989698

Answer (score 1):

if you have installed google-cloud-sdk via `snap`, you have to modify path vaiable.Add snap directory to **PATH** as `export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin`
This worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If using zsh , source

> source ~/.zshrc

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was because the `~/.bash_profile` had invalid `fi` statements.

The fix:

1. Execute command `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`
2. Removed closing `fi` statements *(the ones missing an opening `if`)*
3. Save .bash_profile changes
4. Execute command `source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo su
$ /opt/google-appengine-sdk/bin/gcloud components update
$ su <yourusername>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now after running `install.sh` in `Mac OS`, google itself giving the information to run `completion.bash.inc` and `path.bash.inc`.

If you're using `zsh` terminal, it'll ask you to run `completion.zsh.inc` and `path.zsh.inc`. Please see the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a very different story here that turned out to be caused by my **Python virtual environments**.

Somewhere in the middle of running `curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash`, I was getting **error**:

```
~/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
pyenv: python2: command not found

The `python2' command exists in these Python versions:
  2.7.14
  miniconda2-latest
```

**solution** I've modified `google-cloud-sdk/install.sh` script:

```
# if CLOUDSDK_PYTHON is empty
if [ -z "$CLOUDSDK_PYTHON" ]; then
  # if python2 exists then plain python may point to a version != 2
  #if _cloudsdk_which python2 >/dev/null; then
  #  CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python2
  if _cloudsdk_which python2.7 >/dev/null; then
    # this is what some OS X versions call their built-in Python
    CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python2.7
```

and was able to run the installation successfully. 
However, I still need to activate my pyenv that has `python2` command to run `gcloud`.

**why so**

If you look at the `google-cloud-sdk/install.sh` script, you'll see that it's actually checking for versions of Python in a very brute manner:

```
if [ -z "$CLOUDSDK_PYTHON" ]; then
  # if python2 exists then plain python may point to a version != 2
  if _cloudsdk_which python2 >/dev/null; then
    CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python2
```

However, on my machine `python2` doesn't point to Python binary, neither returns null.  So the installation crashed.

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
emacs -nw ~/.zshrc
And add following line at the beginning:

# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
source '/home/lesaint/GOOGLE_CLOUD/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc'

#The next lines enables bash completion in Zsh for gcloud. 
autoload -U compinit compdef
compinit
source '/home/lesaint/GOOGLE_CLOUD/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc'
```

The solution proposed by following article works for me:

Referencee:
http://www.javatronic.fr/tips/2014/10/17/installing_google_cloud_sdk_on_ubuntu_with_oh-my-zsh.html

Check my solution:
[-bash: gcloud: command not found on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46144267/bash-gcloud-command-not-found-on-mac/60670086#60670086)

Answer (score 0):

The thing that I did wrong was failing to choose the right download for my OS. I accidentally choose Apple Intel instead of Apple Silicon. Even though the installation appeared to work, I was unable to use the `gcloud` command. Once I deleted the folder and reinstalled the correct Apple Silicon version, everything worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue where after running `./install.sh` and following all the steps, when I tried to check the version using `gcloud --version`

It gave me this error: `zsh: command not found: gcloud`

After going through all the answers here and searching through some websites, I found a webpage which provided the answer that worked for me. This is the link to the website: [gcloud command not found – While Installing Google Cloud SDK](https://www.bacancytechnology.com/qanda/cloud/gcloud-command-not-found)

The basic gist is that once you go through the entire set up the .bash_profile is automatically modified, but sometimes that does not happen.

So at that time, rerun `./install.sh` and when the prompt appears to change the path `Modify profile to update your $PATH and enable shell command completion? Do you want to continue (Y/n)?` enter Y and then set the path to `~/.profile`.

This worked for me, I hope it does for you too. Have a nice day :))

Answer (score -1):

It's worked for me:

1. Download SDK from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install
2. Extract the archive to my home directory (my home is "nintran")
3. Run "./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init"