# GCloud commands not working with SSH (gcloud app deploy)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, deployment, gcloud

I am trying to do host this static website on Google App Engine and I am stuck on this crucial part of the process:

```
-bash: gcloud: command not found
```

I get into Google Cloud Platform, then login into the SSH, look for the files, then when I try to deploy, nothing happens. The two main files in this equation include: app.yaml and www (www containing the html and files). I am grabbing a file with a html, then making it the index.html. The index.html is what you see when you open the website after compiling the file(s) (with the command "gcloud app deploy"). After a couple other steps, it becomes available to view on the static website.

I have been trying to find a solution for a few hours now.

Here is what the code looks right now when trying to deploy:

```
vergil11$ cd Files
vergil11$ ls
websitegc
vergil11$ cd websitegc
vergil11$ ls
app.yaml  IMD233  Files  README.md  www
vergil11$ gcloud app deploy
-bash: gcloud: command not found
vergil11$
```

Any help provided, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add gloud on your `%PATH%` (Windows) or `$PATH` (Linux/Mac)

- See [here for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46144267/6309)
- Or "[How To Install Google Cloud GCP Command Line Utility gcloud ?](https://gankrin.org/how-to-install-google-cloud-gcp-command-line-utility-gcloud/)" for Windows.
- [Here for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41434645/6309), modifying your `~/.profile`

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: One more question, it is possible to gcloud app deploy in a ssh

Comment: @user15056935 Yes, but SSH by default does not set environment variables, so you would have to execute a script settings at least PATH in order to reference the gcloud command in that remote SSH session.