# Google cloud SDK installation error: Could not update [/Users/username/.bash_profile]. Ensure you have write access to this location

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, failed-installation, google-cloud-sdk

I am getting the above error while installing Google cloud sdk.

I entered below command in terminal:

curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash

Thanks

Comment: Run `source ~/.bash_profile` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037279/gcloud-command-not-found-while-installing-google-cloud-sdk).

Comment: thanks for your response I read the other post and tried this command already but it did not fix the issue. It seems like issue is with permission to my profile so may be i need chmode command to give permission to the user.  I will try your command and chmod as well and update here if that helps

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR (copy and paste in 2 steps, )

Step 1 (gcloud will prompt for input):

```
sudo chown $(whoami):staff ~/.bash_profile
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

Step 2:

```
sudo chown root:staff ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

### Explanation:

`~/.bash_profile` is owned by the `root`user, so it requires `sudo` and therefore the root password. The command `curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash` does not have permission to edit it. My solution here was to change ownership of the file for the installation of `gcloud` and then revert it back to `root` after the installation was completed.

1. Change ownership of the file `sudo chown $(whoami):staff ~/.bash_profile`

   - This command will probably prompt for password
   - `$(whoami)` will be replaced by the currently logged in user.
   - `staff` is just the already existing group
2. Run installation command and proceed to respond input prompts `$ curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash`
3. Reset `root` ownership to the profile for security reasons `sudo chown root:staff ~/.bash_profile`
4. Reload shell to make gcloud commands available `$ source ~/.bash_profile`

### Important Note

I tried `sudo curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash` but it did not work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely happened when the SDK's installation script attempted to modify your `.bashrc` in order to add `gcloud` (and others) to your profile's `PATH` environment variable. The script attempted to change the file, but didn't have enough permissions to do it, thus failed. I recommend making sure you or the user installing the SDK can modify their own `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR (copy and paste)

`curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | sudo bash`

### Explanation

On my first answer I noted that

`sudo curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash`

didn't work, adding the `sudo` in front of `bash` seems to have the intended effect, rather than on the `curl` command. This should be simpler than changing ownership back and forth.