# Google Cloud access through JupyterLab bash

Tags: python, bash, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

**1. Problem:**
Unable to run basic `!gcloud ...` commands in JupyterLab (.ipynb file). Runs fine in terminal (no '!'), as well as Jupyter Notebook.

**2. Attempted:**
Same user, same Anaconda environment in all three instances. 
Tried installing Google Cloud again anyway in JupyterLab and it reads the Google Cloud files already exist.

**3. Context:**
Using this file for a couple commands to scoop and delete temp/test tables from a BigQuery dataset intermittently based on keyword.

Ideally, I could keep bash and python files solely within JupyterLab as Notebook will eventually phase out.

Comment: Are you in an AI Platform JupyterLab? Could you show the error message you are getting? Also, have you checked if the Google Cloud package is in your package list?

Comment: @Ksign error message when running `!gcloud info` is that package isn't found. `/bin/sh: gcloud: command not found` I'm launching JupyterLab in browser from the base/root environment in Anaconda MacOS desktop app if that answers your question. GCP package is confirmed in all environments (root and condas)

Comment: You could try to follow these steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037279/gcloud-command-not-found-while-installing-google-cloud-sdk) or [here](https://intellipaat.com/community/3063/gcloud-command-not-found-while-installing-google-cloud-sdk) to reinstall the Google Cloud sdk. Also, just in case of an extension conflict, run your notebook in an incognito window and try again.

Comment: Additionally, run the `!sudo service jupyter status` command and post the ouptut.

Comment: No changes after reinstall and incognito. `!sudo service jupyter status` output is a prompt for password: `sudo apt-get update service jupyter status service jupyter status
Password:`