# Can't use gsutil cp with gitlab CI

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci, gsutil

I'm using gitlab runner on a mac mini server.
While using user named "runner" I manage to use this command:

```
gsutil ls -l gs://tests/ |grep staging | sort -k 2 | tail -n 3| head -n 2 |awk '{print $3}' | gsutil -m cp -I .
```

I manage to get the files, but while using the same command in gitlab-ci.yml like this:

```
stages:
  - test
test:
  stage: test
  when: always
  script:
    - gsutil ls -l gs://tests/ |grep staging | sort -k 2 | tail -n 3| head -n 2 |awk '{print $3}' | gsutil -m cp -I .
```

I get the error:

```
bash: line 141: gsutil: command not found
```

Also I checked and gitlab runner is using the same user I used.

The gitlab runner is configured with shell executor.

Changing the command to hold the full path of gsutil didn't help either.

I added `whoami` to the gitlab-ci.yml and got the result of the same user "runner"

Comment: Even when the runner is configured to use the shell executor, it runs as a different user: `gitlab-runner`. Make sure that, that user has access to `gsutil`. What's the output of `whereis gsutil` and `which gsutil` when you're logged in with your user account?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this error happens even while using the full path I get from `which gsutil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by using this solution:

[gcloud-command-not-found-while-installing-google-cloud-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037279/gcloud-command-not-found-while-installing-google-cloud-sdk#:%7E:text=%23%20The%20next%20line%20updates%20PATH%20for%20the%20Google%20Cloud%20SDK.%0Asource%20%27%5Bpath-to-my-home%5D/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc%27%0A%23%20The%20next%20line%20enables%20bash%20completion%20for%20gcloud.%0Asource%20%27%5Bpath-to-my-home%5D/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc%27)

I included this 2 line into my gitlab-ci.yml before using the gsutil command.

```
source '[path-to-my-home]/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'
source '[path-to-my-home]/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
```